# Enable to see vote counts on the mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, vote-count

When you're an established user you can see vote counts on the site.
Evidently, you can't do that on the site, though it's useful information.

Comment: This is my number 1 reason for going to desktop mode while on mobile (app or otherwise)